# iOS simulator reboots between runtimes and start

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

[iOS Rebooting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2UpB.png)

Whenever I run my application in Xcode. The simulator starts but not directly. It reboots. I tried both iOS 9.0 and 9.1, both of them take a lot of time starting and eventually run the application. I didn't face this issue while using Xcode 6 with iOS 8. Currently, I'm using Xcode 7 with iOS 9.0/9.1. I tried resetting content and settings but it didn't change anything. I have command line tools installed properly.

Comment: Are you running them from xcode or from the command line?

Comment: I'm running from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It will only boot up a different simulator device if you deploy to a device that isn't booted.  If your run destination is the same as the booted device, it will not shutdown the booted device and boot a new one.  This is not new to Xcode 7.  It has always been this way.